# I have a program whose windowed mode cannot be resized. Any trick/app to force resize?

Tags: window, fullscreen

It can't resize or maximize. I'm on windows 7 64bit.

I remember programs where fans have made simple directx apps that launched fullscreen-only games in a window. Is there any app or script I can run that might work with this game?

Comment: It's likely that a utility that can force the window to be resizeable won't cause the program to stretch its canvas throughout the entire breadth and height of the window.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a workable solution I found *exactly* a decade ago in 2003, that still works today (tested on Windows 7 x64).

It works for most fix-sized games I've tried it on, including Diablo 2, Starcraft 1, and both Governors of Poker, including virtually every windows screen, including popup message boxes.

[Download page for `ResizeEnable`](http://www.digitallis.co.uk/pc/downloads.html).

([`ResizeEnable` direct link](http://www.digitallis.co.uk/pc/downloads/ResizeEnable.zip))

Answer (score 0):

Turn down your desktop resolution to a closer match to the window's size.

Perhaps right-click the icon-->Properties-->Compatibility tab and check-mark "Run in 640x480" and see if that suits it.

Comment: just a followup, I did try that and the program ran at the same size, but I only saw the bottom right corner of it (about 640x480 pixels of it, but not the rest sadly). I also tried the program "alt-move" and it did resize, but there were some problems that made the game tough to play (hovering over certain areas like the game start button caused the mouse to jump over and seemingly avoid the areas. Fullscreening solved that but then I have to resize). So, not a perfect fix, but it was what I was looking for.

Comment: Did you try lowering your desktop resolution to something smaller, yet larger than 640-x480 (right click the desktop-->Screen Resolution)?